# How to change position of paragraph inside TD?

Tags: html, css

I want to place Authorised signatory text that located at last column position is bottom of TD. I tried valign but that method not worked. Now, How can I change the position of text "Authorised signatory" and place text in the bottom of TD? Thanks in advance and sorry for grammatical mistake if I made.

```css
tr.border_bottom td{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="border_bottom">
    <td style="text-align: left;width: 12.6cm;padding-right: 0px; border: solid #000; border-width: 1px 1px 0 0">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;width: 6.3cm;padding-right: 0px; border-right: 1px solid #000">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;margin: 0">Bank : HDFC Bank Ltd.</p>
          </td>
          <td style="text-align: left;width: 6.3cm;padding-right: 0px;text-align: center;" rowspan="4" valign="bottom">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;padding: 10px 0 10px 0;border-top: 1px solid #000;margin: 0">Common Seal </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;width: 6.3cm;padding-right: 0px; border-right: 1px solid #000">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;margin: 0">Bank A/C : 50200003685662</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;width: 6.3cm;padding-right: 0px; border-right: 1px solid #000">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;margin: 0">Bank IFSC : HDFC0000069</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;width: 6.3cm;padding-right: 5px; border-right: 1px solid #000;">
            <p style="font-size: 12px;margin: 10PX 0 10PX 0; text-align: justify;"><b>TERMS:</b> <br> Interest @ 24% p.a. will be charged. if this invoice is not paid by the date. No. complaints in repsect of material supplied wide this invoice will be entertained unless the same is lodged in within 15 days of despatch Subject to Ahmedabad Jurisdiction.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: left;width: 8.4cm;padding-right: 0px; border: solid #000; border-width: 1px 1px 0 0"  valign="top">
      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;width: 8.4cm;padding-right: 0px">
            <div style="float: left;width: 70%; border-right: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 5px">
              <p style="text-align: left;font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;margin: 0">GST On Reverse Charge: </p>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left;width: 30%"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;width: 8.4cm;padding-right: 0px;border: none">
            <p style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;margin: 7px 0 0 0">Certified that particular given above is true and correct</p>
            <p style="text-align: center;font-size: 16px;margin: 3px 0 0 0">For, <b>SHRI ABICA PLASTIC INDUSTRIES</b></p>
            <p style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;margin: 3px 0 0 0">Authorised signatory</b></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest approach would be placing `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` for corresponding `p` element and `position: relative` for right `td` of whole table. For sure getting rid of nested tables and using (for example) flexbox approach would be easier and cleaner, but I don't want to alter to much your styles.

#### Snippet

```css
tr.border_bottom td{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="border_bottom">
    <td style="text-align: left;width: 12.6cm;padding-right: 0px; border: solid #000; border-width: 1px 1px 0 0">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;width: 6.3cm;padding-right: 0px; border-right: 1px solid #000">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;margin: 0">Bank : HDFC Bank Ltd.</p>
          </td>
          <td style="text-align: left;width: 6.3cm;padding-right: 0px;text-align: center;" rowspan="4" valign="bottom">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;padding: 10px 0 10px 0;border-top: 1px solid #000;margin: 0">Common Seal </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;width: 6.3cm;padding-right: 0px; border-right: 1px solid #000">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;margin: 0">Bank A/C : 50200003685662</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;width: 6.3cm;padding-right: 0px; border-right: 1px solid #000">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;margin: 0">Bank IFSC : HDFC0000069</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;width: 6.3cm;padding-right: 5px; border-right: 1px solid #000;">
            <p style="font-size: 12px;margin: 10PX 0 10PX 0; text-align: justify;"><b>TERMS:</b> <br> Interest @ 24% p.a. will be charged. if this invoice is not paid by the date. No. complaints in repsect of material supplied wide this invoice will be entertained unless the same is lodged in within 15 days of despatch Subject to Ahmedabad Jurisdiction.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="position: relative; text-align: left;width: 8.4cm;padding-right: 0px; border: solid #000; border-width: 1px 1px 0 0"  valign="top">
      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;width: 8.4cm;padding-right: 0px">
            <div style="float: left;width: 70%; border-right: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 5px">
              <p style="text-align: left;font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;margin: 0">GST On Reverse Charge: </p>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left;width: 30%"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;width: 8.4cm;padding-right: 0px;border: none">
            <p style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;margin: 7px 0 0 0">Certified that particular given above is true and correct</p>
            <p style="text-align: center;font-size: 16px;margin: 3px 0 0 0">For, <b>SHRI ABICA PLASTIC INDUSTRIES</b></p>
            <p style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%; text-align: center;font-size: 12px;margin: 3px 0 0 0">Authorised signatory</b></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```